# Pinescript - How does the qty for strategy.exit() change by itself?

Tags: pine-script

So I was trying to create a strategy with multiple exits and dynamic qty/order size, somehow through trial and error I accidently got the results I wanted. Apparently the qty for strategy.exit() changes by itself and I wanted to know how it happens.

```
if enableTP2 and longCondition
    strategy.entry("long", strategy.long, 1)
    strategy.exit("long sl", "long", 1, stop=longSL)
    strategy.order("long tp", strategy.short, 0.5, limit=longTP)
    strategy.order("long tp2", strategy.short, 0.5, limit=longTP2)
```

From the code above, when the long condition is met I enter long with qty of 1. I set a stop loss with a qty of 1, take profit qty of 0.5, and second take profit qty of 0.5.

[image]

From the screenshot above, it does exactly what you expect the code to do. When it hits your stop loss, it exits with qty of 1.

[image]

Now from the screenshot above, it also does exactly what you expect the code to do. When it hits your tp and tp2, they both close with qty of 0.5.

[image]

But now if you look at the last screenshot, it hits tp first partially closes with 0.5, then hits stop loss but closes with a qty of 0.5.

I set the stop loss to close with qty of 1 but somehow it closes with 0.5. I'm not complaining, this is exactly the result that I wanted, but I just don't understand how it happened. Can someone enlighten me?

Answer (score 1):

Your sl & tp exits is not linked to each other, i.e. when stop loss filled, take profits is not cancelled and can will be filled later.

There are 2 descisions.

1. With `strategy.order`:

```
if enableTP2 and longCondition
    strategy.entry("long", strategy.long, 1)
    strategy.order("long sl", strategy.short, 1, stop=longSL, oca_name = "exit", oca_type = strategy.oca.reduce)
    strategy.order("long tp", strategy.short, 0.5, limit=longTP, oca_name = "exit", oca_type = strategy.oca.reduce)
    strategy.order("long tp2", strategy.short, 0.5, limit=longTP2, oca_name = "exit", oca_type = strategy.oca.reduce)

if strategy.position_size == 0
    strategy.cancel("long sl")
    strategy.cancel("long tp")
    strategy.cancel("long tp2")
```

2. With `strategy.exit`:

```
if enableTP2 and longCondition
    strategy.entry("long", strategy.long, 1)
    strategy.exit("x1", qty = 0.5, stop=longSL, limit=longTP)
    strategy.exit("x2", qty = 1, stop=longSL, limit=longTP2)
```

Comment: Thank you for reminding me to cancel the orders that are not being used. Though this was not the answer I was looking for. But I think the reason as to why the qty for strategy.exit() changed from 1 to 0.5 is because strategy.exit() can only exit the amount/qty that is currently open, regardless if you put 100 or 1000. When my tp got hit, it exits with a qty of 0.5, meaning there is only 0.5 left available, therefore when it hit my stop loss, it exited only for 0.5.